What's the weird pink border in AC: Rogue?
Sometimes during missions where stealth seems to be somewhat important, an odd pink border shows up at the edges of the screen. I also notice it when there are hidden enemies that will try to ambush me (such as Stalkers or gang captains).
An example can be seen in this video at 0:03, and the border disappears when Cormac jumps into the hay wagon.
What's the exact trigger that activates the border? What is it supposed to signify?

This border is meant to warn you that Stalkers are nearby. Their presence is also announced with whispering sounds (though I didn't notice these). It's possible that the border shows up when other hidden enemies are nearby.
According to IGN

Their presence is notified by whispering sounds and a unique border
around the edge of the screen.


I realize you wanted "evidence" (or an external source to back it up), but now that you have it, the older answer turns out to be right. It's better form to just accept that one (and maybe edit out the "I think").

I think the pink border in AC: Rogue shows up to warn you that hidden enemies, like Stalkers, are nearby and you're in danger of being ambushed.

Could you explain why you think that, and back it up with evidence? Otherwise, it's better left as a comment.
